# Howto generate a gallery preview in the main index in Hugo

Tags: image-gallery, hugo

I'm using Hugo to present my photos in a simple gallery with multiple albums. There are only 2 elements in this setup:

- album page: one content item  `content/img/album[x].md`for each album. `content/img/album[x].md` just shows all the image in a directory.
- main index list: a main index with a list of links to each album inside `content/img/`

I'm generating `content/img/album[x].md` with a script that scans a directory under `static/archive/...` for subdirectories and generate a a .md file for each directory.

Currently the *main index* is a ***list of links***. However what I would like 
is a little ***preview*** (i.e. the first 4 pictures) of that album. So what I wonder is:

- How can I render `content/img/album[x].md` depending on the context it is shown in (main index list versus album page)?
- Is it possible to propagate a context variable to `content/img/album[x].md` that shows where it is rendered (so that I can use it in a `if else` statement inside content/img/album[x].md )?
- Is it possible to declare other tags than `{{ .Content }}` or `{{ .Summary }}` that I can use depending on context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to add metadata to the params field of the content item, i.e.:

```
++++
files = [ ["data/2013-08-16/thumbs/thumb_2013-08-16_09:49:32_IMG_7101.JPG","rotate-90"],["data/2013-08-16/thumbs/thumb_2013-08-16_10:39:55_IMG_7113.JPG","rotate-0"] ]
++++
```

Then I switch layout for each page:

```
{{ range .Pages }}
{{ .Render "articlepreview"}}
{{ end }}
```

Inside the patial template articlepreview.html I use the metadata array:

```
{{ range .Params.files }}
<img width="100" src="{{ index . 0 }}" class="{{ index . 1 }}">
{{end}}
```